# iOS: augmented reality, add object to cam

Tags: ios, augmented-reality

I am working on an iOS app which has a little augmented reality part. Namely, I want to highlight a geolocation point using the cam. For instance, assume I have a friend address and coordinate. I go to that place but do not find the house. I want using my cam to display an arrow next to the house (I know the precision won't be that good but precision is not the purpose of the app, it is just an example to explain the principle).

So, here is the question. How can I do it simply ? Using a framework ? Which one ? Doing simple calculation using geolocation and the gyroscopic information of the iPhone.

Thanks!

Comment: This tutorial is slightly outdated but might give you a starting kick: [iOS Camera Overlay Example Using AVCaptureSession](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273) and comes with a GitHub source.

Comment: You have multiple questions here, so this is pretty broad. You asked how to overlay an image on the camera view. You asked how to use CoreLocation. You asked how to use the device gyroscope and compass. Then you sort of answered your own question. I didn't make this an answer because it's not answer worthy, but yes, you'd just CoreLocation and CoreMotion and listen for callbacks on orientation, and do calculations based on those callbacks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this augmented reality library: https://github.com/nielswh/iPhone-AR-Toolkit. I'm using it in one project and it is quite good. Thanks to developer working on it :)
Library is handling all calculations, drawings and gyroscope data for you so you don't have to hassle with it.

There is also a good AR tutorial that uses mentioned iPhone-AR-Toolkit. Here is tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/42266/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based.